# How to copy directories and files from one external to another C# Console

Tags: c#, file, directory, copy

I have had HORRIBLE luck with external drives failing and on numerous occasions almost lost EVERYTHING.  Finally I had the idea to create a console app that automatically "raids" my two drives. Now as far as getting directory info I got it. For some reason though when I try to copy from one to the other it says access denied? Any ideas? This is what I have done so far. (I am just doing my movies and TV for testing first)

The error is "UNAUTHORIZED ACCESS EXCEPTION: Access to the path 'D:\External Backup\Movies and TV\Alien Quadrilogy' is denied."

```
        string _movieDIR = @"D:\External Backup\Movies and TV";
        string _movieDIR2 = @"G:\TEMP";
        string[] movies = Directory.GetDirectories(_movieDIR);


        foreach(string movie in movies)
        {
            File.Copy(movie, _movieDIR2);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

### UPDATED COMPLETED CODE

```
        string _movieDIR = @"D:\External Backup\Movies and TV";
        string _movieDIR2 = @"G:\Movies and TV";
        string[] movies = Directory.GetDirectories(_movieDIR);

        if(Directory.Exists(@"G:\Movies and TV")){
            Console.WriteLine("Purging old Movies Folder in G:");
            Directory.Delete(@"G:\Movies and TV",true);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Creating New Movies Folder in G:");
        Directory.CreateDirectory(@"G:\Movies and TV");

        double size = movies.Length;
        double percent = 0.00;
        double counter = 0;

        foreach(string movie in movies)
        {

           Console.Write("\n\nCopying " + movie.ToString());
           int pos = movie.IndexOf(@"V\");
           Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(movie, _movieDIR2+ @"\" + movie.Substring(pos+2).ToString(),true);

           counter++;               
           percent = (counter / size)*100;
           percent = Math.Round(percent,2);
           Console.WriteLine("\n\nPercent Copied " + percent + "%\n\n");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: You are calling `GetDirectories` and iterating over the results assuming they are files. I think youre after `GetFiles`..

Comment: You are correct that the above code will not work. I just tried it with two local directories and it failed with an error saying that "blank is a directory and not a file" HOWEVER that is not the same as an unauthorized access error so there is something else afoot.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you add another backslash to your directory strings? (E.g. `@"G:\TEMP\"`)

Comment: @SimonWhitehead good thinking but still an access issue.

Comment: Non-programming answer - consider if existing tools like [xcopy](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx?mfr=true) (part of Windows) or [robocopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145(v=WS.10).aspx) will do the job...

Comment: @AMR See my answer. It fixes your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to copy directoies you can use the handy `FileIO` methods from the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace.

```
    string _movieDIR = @"D:\External Backup\Movies and TV";
    string _movieDIR2 = @"G:\TEMP";
    string[] movies = Directory.GetDirectories(_movieDIR);

    foreach(string movie in movies)
    {
        Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(_movieDIR, _movieDIR2);
    }
```

Comment: It's still not a "permissions" issue. There are certain APIs that when passed a folder when expecting a file, you'll get unauthorized access exceptions. They are misleading, but intentional.

Comment: Well thank you to @sa_ddam213 and everyone else that helped make this dream a reality

Comment: As @x0n mentioned, these errors are caused by many things. You shouldn't have to rely on this answer to make it happen.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead, whats wrong with using `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.CopyDirectory` over iterating over every file?

Comment: @sa_ddam213 You're relying on a library you don't have to rely on. There is nothing wrong with that.. but you shouldn't have to rely on it.. which means there is something wrong with the code (which I've now supplied my own answer for).

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I want to try your's as well (though I think I already did) and as soon as this batch has transferred I will. I think that I already tried that and that there was still an issue. Did you use two external drives?

Comment: @AMR Remember you also had other issues, such as iterating over directories, etc. If you iterate over files, it will work. I used one external USB and a local drive in my test and it was fine.

Comment: Yeah I know the directories was an issue also however instead of having to do some crazy recursion alg like I thought I was going to have to do this VisualBasic function does EVERYTHING. It may be a deprecated function but I follow kiss mentality. That code is clean and small. If it works it works. Since I haven't tried yours yet though can you tell me if it copies all directories and files in one shot?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead, Its not really relying on the library, It just using a library that is right for the job, I perfer the VB lib for coping files because its clean and simple, plus it has the functionality to show progress to the user and option like overwrite, Rename and cancel prompts, No point reinventing the wheel when the framwork has one ready. But thats just my opinion, some people may prefer to write the exact same function from scratc and pull in the WinAPI to show the progress dialog, its really up to the Dev what they prefer

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using File.Copy to try to copy Directories.

Try using the code from the example in the following link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc148994.aspx

Comment: As I mentioned above -- You are correct that the above code will not work. I just tried it with two local directories and it failed with an error saying that "blank is a directory and not a file" HOWEVER that is not the same as an unauthorized access error so there is something else afoot.

Comment: There seems to be a permissions issue going on

Comment: That is likely. Make sure you can copy the files manually using Windows Explorer. If you are going to be running your console app as a service make sure whatever account it is running under also has permissions on the drives.

Comment: I have full access to both drives for read/write/delete on this and all accounts. As for a service I considered scheduling it but right now just being able to double click it when I want would suffice

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to copy directories, which you can't. You need to iterate over each file and copy them individually. You will also need some code to make sure the correct folders trees are replicated in your target directory

Comment: once again... I have corrected the directory issue. The error is a permissions issue not a directory problem.

Comment: Youre right that I was wrong about permissions however this answer is still incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a "permissions" issue in the sense you think. Everyone who says it's because you're passing folders to APIs that expects files is correct. This can be verified quite simply (using powershell here):

```
ps c:\temp> [io.file]::openwrite("c:\temp")
Exception calling "OpenWrite" with "1" argument(s): "Access to the path 'c:\temp' is denied."
At line:1 char:1                                                                             
+ [io.file]::OpenWrite("c:\temp")                                                            
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                            
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException                
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccessException
```

Yes, it's a bit weird but it's entirely intentional. The underlying win32 APIs will return an access denied HR which ends up as a .NET UAE.

Answer (score 1):

Now that I am back at my desk I can answer fully.

Your code is incorrect. The definition of the `File.Copy` method is:

```
string sourceFileName, string destFileName
```

You need to provide a full path for both. Therefore:

```
foreach(string movie in movies)
{
    File.Copy(movie, _movieDIR2 + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(movie));
    //                          ^^^^^ Extract the filename and append it to the directory
}
```

Essentially, you're saying:

```
Copy D:\file.avi to G:\
```

When you should be saying:

```
 Copy D:\file.avi to G:\file.avi
```

I have verified your code works with the above fix.